# Dynamics Nav 2015 oData service returns just one record

Tags: service, odata, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2015

xxx.xxx.xx/.../Company('XXXX')/FR_CustomerLedgerEntry?$format=json

I want  to get 'Customer ledger Entries' via OData service from Nav 2015

I try oData service URL in the browser but  value array contains only one object while I see a lot of records when running the nav page

other oData service returns multiple objects but only page 25 returns just one record when used the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is there is a limit in page. Check onPageRun method you can find there is limit for only one record. If you delete that line you will have all records.